# Generating a SiteMap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, sitemap

So I designed a website in ruby on rails and it is pretty robust. But i was trying to use one of those generators to generate a sitemap for my website but it always fails. I've tried virtually every sitemap generator there is on the internet but to no avail. I suspect this is because most pages require you to be logged in before you can access it. So how would i go about generating a sitemap for such a site.

The website is: http://dev.forwardag.com.

Answer (score 0):

Josh

maybe using a gem to generate the sitemap  ?

https://rubygems.org/gems/sitemap_generato[1](https://rubygems.org/gems/sitemap_generator)

or use a online xml sitemap generator ( just google it )